# Decimal string format truncates the zero left to the decimal point

Tags: c#

I'm calling the below method with `0.02`

```
public static string FormatAsDecimalWithCommaSeperator(decimal value)
{
    return String.Format("{0:#,###,###.##}", value);
}
```

returns `.02`

All I want to do is to leave two decimal digits and leave the zero left to the decimal point. Meaning in that case it should have returned `"0.02"`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily have googled. Here, I found this.

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

So the answer is `"{0:#,###,##0.##}"`

Comment: I think I typed `c# string format show 0 decimal point` into Google, and then this link showed up on top.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String.Format("{0:#,###,##0.##}", value);
```